# Ruby on Rails: Activerecord collection associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models as follows:

```
class Bookshelf < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
    scope    :in_stock, -> { where(in_stock: true) }
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bookshelf
end
```

I would like to find all the books in a collection of bookshelves based on a column in the bookshelf table efficiently.
At the moment I have to loop through each member as follows:

```
available_bookshelves = Bookshelf.in_stock
```

This returns an activerecord relation
To retrieve all the books in the relation, i am looping through the relation as follows:

```
available_bookshelves.each do |this_bookshelf|
    this_bookshelf.books.each do |this_book|
        process_isbn this_book
    end
end
```

I would like all the books from the query so that I don't have to loop through each "bookshelf" from the collection returned individually. This works but feels verbose. I have other parts of the app where similar queries-loops are being performed.

EDIT:

Some clarification: Is there a way to get all books in all bookshelves that fit a certain criteria?
For example, if there are 5 brown bookshelves, can we retrieve all the books in those bookshelves?
something like (this is not valid code)
    brown_books = books where bookshelf is brown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the books in the in stock book shelves

```
available_books = Book.where(bookshelf_id: Bookshelf.in_stock.select(:id))
```

That will run a single query which will look like:

```
SELECT books.*
FROM books
WHERE books.bookshelf_id IN (SELECT id FROM bookshelves WHERE in_stock = true)
```

Comment: Great! This seems to preserve the results from the order of the ids returned by `Bookshelf.in_stock`